# Posting photos from iPhoto to Facebook

Tags: photos.app, photos, photo-stream, facebook

I want to make a Facebook post consisting of several selected photos from my photo stream in iPhoto. For some reason this appears to be extremely difficult. What am I missing?

Steps I've tried so far:

1. Find the first of the photos I want to post
2. Click on "My Photo Stream", select the thumbnail, and press CMD-C. (Because for some reason you're not allowed to copy the photo while you're actually looking at it.)
3. Attempt to paste the photo into a Facebook post. This flatly doesn't work; nothing happens.
4. Try clicking "upload photo" in Facebook instead. I'm presented with a file dialogue. I suppose I could click "reveal in Finder" in iPhoto and drag the file into this dialogue, but I mean, come on, I'm not going to do that for every single photo.

So what are my options? I've seen several forum posts from Windows users indicating that on that platform one can just paste photos straight into Facebook posts. Is this impossible on the Mac? Or is there just some extra special thing I've neglected to click on in iPhoto?

**Please Note:** I have "platform" turned off in Facebook for good reasons, which means that clicking "share" and then "Facebook" in iPhoto will not work. I am looking for a way to copy-and-paste photos from iPhoto into another app.

Comment: when you do the CMD-C try paste somewhere else (another app, like notepad ect..) to see if you actuality copied the photo.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that although you can't do it with CMD-C and CMD-V, you can drag and drop the thumbnail of a photo from iPhoto into Facebook. So I did it this way:

- Find a photo I want to post
- Press the space bar to go back to the thumbnail view. The thumbnail of the photo I was looking at is highlighted in yellow.
- Click-and-drag the highlighted thumbnail and, while holding the mouse button down, press CMD-tab to switch to the browser
- Drop the photo into Facebook
- Repeat for other photos until the post is finished

It's not exactly ideal but it did work. I won't accept my own answer in case someone has a better way.